# Sequence contains no matching element error when a table is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting this error when a table is empty. That is, when the model has no value I am getting this error:

> Sequence contains no matching element

How can I put some logic here to get rid of it?

The problem is here:

```
var emp = model.vm.Single(i => i.JobseekerId == id);
```

What I have tried is:

```
public ActionResult JobSeekerProfile(ViewModel model)
{
    if (Session["LogedUserID"] != null)
    {
        JobContext jcntxt = new JobContext();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LogedUserID"]);
        model.vm = from jr in jcntxt.JobseekerRegestrations
                   join jc in jcntxt.JobseekerContactdetails on jr.JobseekerId equals jc.JobseekerId
                   join jb in jcntxt.JobseekerBackgroundDetails on jc.JobseekerId equals jb.JobseekerId
                   join jj in jcntxt.JobseekerJobDetails on jc.JobseekerId equals jj.JobseekerId
                   select new ViewModel
                   {
                       JobseekerId = jr.JobseekerId,
                       FirstName = jc.FirstName,
                       LastName = jc.LastName,
                       EmailID = jc.EmailID,
                       JobTitle = jj.JobTitle,
                       Location1 = jj.Location1,
                       University = jb.University,
                       TechnicalExp = jb.TechnicalExp,
                       WorkField = jb.WorkField
                   };

        var job = model.vm.Single(i => i.JobseekerId == id);
        model.FirstName = job.FirstName;
        model.LastName = job.LastName;
        model.EmailID = job.EmailID;
        model.JobTitle = job.JobTitle;
        model.Location1 = job.Location1;
        model.University = job.University;
        model.TechnicalExp = job.TechnicalExp;
        model.WorkField = job.WorkField;
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("JobSeekerLogin");
    }
}
```

#### View

```
@model Sample.Models.ViewModel
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
        <table class="table table-user-information">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td>@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Single` expects there to *always* we exactly 1 result. Zero or more than 1 will result in an exception.

Perhaps you want to use `SingleOrDefault` instead, however once you do that `job` could be null - and in that instance your next line will error with `NullReferenceException` - so make sure you trap that:

```
var job = model.vm.SingleOrDefault(i => i.JobseekerId == id);
if (job != null)
{
    model.FirstName = job.FirstName;
    model.LastName = job.LastName;
    model.EmailID = job.EmailID;
    model.JobTitle = job.JobTitle;
    model.Location1 = job.Location1;                
    model.University = job.University;
    model.TechnicalExp = job.TechnicalExp;
    model.WorkField = job.WorkField;
}
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, I did

Answer (score 4):

Use `SingleOrDefault` method and then check if the resultant object is `null`

```
var job = model.vm.Where(i => i.JobseekerId == id).SingleOrDefault();
if (job != null)
{
    model.FirstName = job.FirstName;
    model.LastName = job.LastName;
    model.EmailID = job.EmailID;
    model.JobTitle = job.JobTitle;
    model.Location1 = job.Location1;                
    model.University = job.University;
    model.TechnicalExp = job.TechnicalExp;
    model.WorkField = job.WorkField;
}
```